# how can i create a combinations of element with at most x repetitions for each one

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I would be generate a combinations of a vector x of 5 element  with at most 2 repetitions for each element.

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I'm using `combn(x,5)` but return the combination of 5 element without repetition.

In output I would be like : ((1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4,6), ..., (1,1,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,4), (1,1,2,2,3), ...)

Most important thing is that each element is represented at most  twice. I would like to know if there is a function that can do this.

Comment: please provide the `x` you mentioned and the expected output.

Comment: i have vector x =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), in output i would be like :                                     ((1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,6)....(1,1,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,4),(1,1,2,2,3)....), most important thing is that each element is reperesented at most 2 twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after combinations of multisets. There are a couple of libraries capable of producing the desired output without producing any duplicates combinations: `arrangements` and `RcppAlgos`, which I authored. Here is how you would use it:

```
arrangements::combinations(5, 5, freq = rep(2, 5))

RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(5, 5, freqs = rep(2, 5))
```

Note, the output from both libraries is in lexicographical order. Also, these libraries are written in compiled languages, so they extend well to larger cases.

Comment: thanks, but this function return vector with only two twice,  and i need all vector with at most two twice, so each vector with one value for element

Comment: @antonionuzzo, you can alter how many times each element is repeated by changing the vector passed to `freq(s)`. Also, I’m a little confused as your original post has a case where 1 is repeated twice and your comment to your question says “each element is represented at most 2 twice”

Answer (score 1):

You could just double the elements in `x` using `rep`. Designing your own vector like so gives you total control over the number of repetitions.

```
combn(x,5)
x <- rep(c(1:5),2)
> head(t(combn(x,5)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    1
[3,]    1    2    3    4    2
[4,]    1    2    3    4    3
[5,]    1    2    3    4    4
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

EDIT: as commented, this will generate duplicates, if this is not what you want, you could use `unique(t(combn...)))` to remove these duplicates.

Comment: your method will generate replicate combinations! For example : `x <- rep(c(1:3), 2) ; t(combn(x, 2))`

Comment: As @DarrenTsai points out, this will produce 252 results when there should only be 51.